# jQuery code not working in Firefox through xampp, while it does in other browers through xampp and locally with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My jQuery code isn't working with xampp in Firefox **only**, though it **does** when I locally open the html file in Firefox. It also **does** work with xampp in Edge, Chrome and IE. Here is the **jQuery** code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        // Hightlight the menu button of the current page by comparing its href to the current url.
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.navMenu a').each(function() {
            if (url == (this.href)){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
        // Highlight the login button if pressed and remove the highlights on other menu buttons.
        $('.loginButton').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.login').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Here is my **html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <title>The Restaurant | Home</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
        <script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/UI.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <figure>
                <a href="home.html"><img src="../images/storelogo.png" alt="Logo of the store"></a>
            </figure>
            <nav>
                <navigation-menu></navigation-menu>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <login-menu></login-menu>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **jQuery** code is in the **UI.js** file. In the **main.js** file this code exists:

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('store', []);

  app.directive('navigationMenu', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'snippets/navigation-menu.html'
    };
  });

})();
```

And at last this is the code in the **navigation-menu.html**:

```
<ul class="navMenu">
  <li><a href="home.html">...</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="tops.html">...</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="bottoms.html">...</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="accessories.html">...</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class ="loginButton">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've already tried several things myself: like mixing the script order and adding the event argument to the click function, but neither of these did work out. One thing I did see was that when I replace the navigation-menu tags with the code that is in navigation-menu.html everything works fine. So somehow the jQuery code gets run before angularjs adds the navigation-menu.html or something? Also the **UI.js** does get run, because an alert message if showing when I place an alert there.

Comment: Have you looked in the [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) for errors?

Comment: Also, if you're using Angular **and** jQuery, you should load jQuery first

Comment: I did look in the browser console, but it isn't showing any errors. I also placed the jQuery script tag above the Angular one, yet the problem remains and it also shows up in other browsers when I do that.

Comment: Did you try your apache logs?

Comment: @Sam Redway I did check the error log and only saw a [ssl:warn] that says "server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name".

Comment: @Phil I think I know what the problem is, but I don't really know how to fix it. The problem is that the jQuery code is executed before angular has loaded the content. So I have to find some way to execute the jQuery only when angular has finished loading the content.

Comment: You should use Angular only

Comment: @Phil I will try to. I still find it strange that it doesn't happen in other browsers and not even locally (instead of using xampp) when using Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. I had to put my jQuery code within a link function within a directive. The link function makes sure it gets run after the directive has been compiled and linked up. If someone wants the solution shown in code, just ask for it in a comment.